# asp.net cms page submenu not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem creating a submenu on my website

i have 2 MSSQL Database tables:

**WWW**

- WWW_ID
- CAT_ID --> FK To Categories
- WWW_NAME

**Categories**

- CAT_ID
- CAT_NAME
- CAT_SORTORDER

**my foreach**

```
    sb.Append("<ul class=\"Menu\">");
    foreach (WWW item in WWW.Fetch(null, null, null))
    {
        if (item.Active)
        {
            //All pages that doesnt have a categorie
            if (!item.Categorie.ID.HasValue)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"page?id={1}\">{0}</a></li>", item.Name, item.ID.ToString());
            }
            //All pages that have a categorie
            if (item.Categorie.ID.HasValue)
            {
                //Split different categories.
                if (CAT != item.Categorie.Name)
                {
                    CAT = item.Categorie.Name;
                    sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"page?id={1}\">{0}</a></li>", item.Categorie.Name, item.ID.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        CAT = "";
    }
    sb.Append("</ul>");
```

Im lost where do i need to create the begining UL and closing UL
and where when do i need to reset my String CAT.
Thanks

Comment: ugh @ whitespace me hates whitespace!

Comment: post the html rendered for this code

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create sub menu inside one node if it contain any category?

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i try to do

Comment: If there are nested items there should definitely be a nested loop. Not sure about the use of CAT variable. All the action should happen within the scope of this statement: if (item.Categorie.ID.HasValue)

Comment: What are you using to build your .NET website? WebForms? MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what the structure of your menu is since you don't have a good example. If however you are doing something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Category</li>
    <li>Catefory
        <ul>
            <li>Page</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<\ul>
```

then you will need to do something like:

```
sb.Append("<ul class=\"Menu\">");
foreach (Categories category in Categories.Fetch(null, null, null))
{
    if (category.Active)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"page?id={1}\">{0}</a>", category.Name, category.ID.ToString());
        var pages = WWW.Fetch(p => p.Categorie.ID.Equals(category.ID));
        if(pages.Any()) {
            sb.Append("<ul>");
            foreach(WWW page in pages) {
                sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"page?id={1}\">{0}</a></li>", page.Name, page.ID.ToString());
            }
            sb.Append("</ul>");
        }
        sb.Append("</li>");
    }
}
sb.Append("</ul>");
```

I realize this isn't exact to your needs most likely, but should be a pretty good example of the logic behind a menu. If you can fill in a little more detail behind how the categories and WWW tables represent the data and also an example of your intended output I am sure I can append a more specific example.

Comment: What if my categories are empty than i dont have any WWW pages so thats not what ya want ??

Comment: The usage above was just an example of how to do nested menus. (the concept of an inner loop to iterate over the "Children" of a menu item.) I am not sure what your table structure is supposed to represent so I just took a stab at an example. If you could show an example of how the menu would look (in html) as well as explain how the tables relate to that html output I can do an example of processing code to show how it would work specifically in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and put the above code in that function and call it recursively when item contain category values something like this:

```
public void NestedMenuCalling(List<Categorie> WWW)
    {
        sb.Append("<ul class=\"Menu\">");
        foreach (WWW item in WWW.Fetch(null, null, null))
        {
            if (item.Active)
            {
                //All pages that doesnt have a categorie
                if (!item.Categorie.ID.HasValue)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"page?id={1}\">{0}</a></li>", item.Name, item.ID.ToString());
                }
                //All pages that have a categorie
                if (item.Categorie.ID.HasValue)
                {
                    //Split different categories.
                    if (CAT != item.Categorie.Name)
                    {
                        CAT = item.Categorie.Name;
                        NestedMenuCalling(item.Categorie);
                    }
                }
            }
            CAT = "";
        }
        sb.Append("</ul>");
    }
```